# Please join us for discussing video games and Autism!

Tags: discussion, chat

We've talked in the past about having featured chat events.  We now have our first topic!

Please feel free to visit our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting) to address the following:

> **Disclaimer:**   *I realize that a lot of folks (including many professionals) think having autistic kids play games is moving them in the wrong direction (away from social interaction).  The friend below, who has both personal and professional experience in this, does think so. And I'd argue that if you can just shift an autistic child toward more social games (without increasing game time) would have little downside. And some folks feel that you should work on your strengths not your weaknesses.*
>
> A friend of my runs an Autism center and has an autistic 5th grader. I've noticed that he really craves social approval (he loves performing for an audience). But a lot of social interactions are just a bit too overwhelming to him while at the same time inscrutable (reading facial expressions).
>
> So I was thinking that a video game (which he loves) where the interaction is rewarded (teams do better than individuals, etc.) but where that interaction is very explicit (chat instead of face to face conversations) might be a good "stepping stone" for him: Interaction that's not overwhelming but also easy to digest (more "literal").
>
> He has access to a Wii, 3DS, and also internet on computer.

Any discussion or feedback on video games and/or Autism is welcome.  Let us know what you think!

Comment: The chat room link gives a 404...

Comment: @RobertArkenin The room had automatically been deleted due to inactivity (7 days).  Please join us in regular [chat] instead.

Comment: OK. Got it. (Filler text for 15 chars)